# XSLT1.0 distinct list of attributes across several nodes

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm stuck on XSLT1.0 with no extensions.

I need to get a list of nodes whose attributes are distinct. From the XML below below, the result should be 1,2,3,5 for the first post_press_version (25) and 1,2,3,6 for the second (26)

```
<order>
<post_press_version>
    <post_press_version_id>25</post_press_version_id>
    <hopper_allocations>
        <hopper_sequence>
            <sequence_id>2</sequence_id>
            <sequence_part_produced_id>37</sequence_part_produced_id>
            <sequence_part_produced_name>96854-12WS10</sequence_part_produced_name>
            <sequence_qty>2</sequence_qty>
            <hopper number="0" id="" is_insert="False"/>
            <hopper number="1" id="23" is_insert="False">96854-6FL</hopper>
            <hopper number="2" id="13" is_insert="False">96854-8FL003</hopper>
            <hopper number="3" id="15" is_insert="False">96854-10FL004</hopper>
            <hopper number="4" id="" is_insert="False"/>
            <hopper number="5" id="" is_insert="False"/>
            <hopper number="6" id="" is_insert="False"/>
        </hopper_sequence>
        <hopper_sequence>
            <sequence_id>3</sequence_id>
            <sequence_part_produced_id>38</sequence_part_produced_id>
            <sequence_part_produced_name>96854-12WS20</sequence_part_produced_name>
            <sequence_qty>250</sequence_qty>
            <hopper number="0" id="" is_insert="False"/>
            <hopper number="1" id="24" is_insert="False">96854-6FL10</hopper>
            <hopper number="2" id="29" is_insert="False">96854-8FL</hopper>
            <hopper number="3" id="" is_insert="False"/>
            <hopper number="4" id="" is_insert="False"/>
            <hopper number="5" id="31" is_insert="False">96854-10FL</hopper>
            <hopper number="6" id="" is_insert="False"/>
        </hopper_sequence>
    </hopper_allocations>
</post_press_version>
<post_press_version>
    <post_press_version_id>26</post_press_version_id>
    <hopper_allocations>
        <hopper_sequence>
            <sequence_id>2</sequence_id>
            <sequence_part_produced_id>37</sequence_part_produced_id>
            <sequence_part_produced_name>96854-12WS10</sequence_part_produced_name>
            <sequence_qty>2</sequence_qty>
            <hopper number="0" id="" is_insert="False"/>
            <hopper number="1" id="23" is_insert="False">96854-6FL</hopper>
            <hopper number="2" id="13" is_insert="False">96854-8FL003</hopper>
            <hopper number="3" id="15" is_insert="False">96854-10FL004</hopper>
            <hopper number="4" id="" is_insert="False"/>
            <hopper number="5" id="" is_insert="False"/>
            <hopper number="6" id="" is_insert="False"/>
        </hopper_sequence>
        <hopper_sequence>
            <sequence_id>3</sequence_id>
            <sequence_part_produced_id>38</sequence_part_produced_id>
            <sequence_part_produced_name>96854-12WS20</sequence_part_produced_name>
            <sequence_qty>250</sequence_qty>
            <hopper number="0" id="" is_insert="False"/>
            <hopper number="1" id="24" is_insert="False">96854-6FL10</hopper>
            <hopper number="2" id="29" is_insert="False">96854-8FL</hopper>
            <hopper number="3" id="" is_insert="False"/>
            <hopper number="4" id="" is_insert="False"/>
            <hopper number="5" id="31" is_insert="False"/>
            <hopper number="6" id="" is_insert="False">96854-10FL</hopper>
        </hopper_sequence>
    </hopper_allocations>
</post_press_version>
```

I tried the XSL below, but it only returns 1,2,3: the results of the first hopper node in the first hopper_sequence

```
   <xsl:template match="order">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each
                    select="/order/post_press_version/hopper_allocations/hopper_sequence/hopper[node() and not(@number = preceding::hopper/@number)]]">
                    <p>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../../post_press_version_id"/>-<xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
                    </p>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>
```

I'm struggling to figure out where I'm goign wrong. I laso tried the Meunchen method with this key, but get similar results

```
<xsl:key name="unique_post_press_version_hoppers" match="/order/post_press_version/hopper_allocations/hopper_sequence/hopper" use="concat(../../../post_press_version_id, @number)"/>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I updated and used your XML and find the proper output as you want. please look again it is correct. Only zero is coming.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the post to have a more complete XML. I also forgot to mention (and include in original code, that it should only select non-empty hopper nodes